# layout_height is not responding in dp

Tags: android, android-layout

in Linear layout image is updating from java. and i want to set image height static. but image height is spreading and this linear layout is inflating in drawer .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="userimagechange"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/lluserImageView"
>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#aaEC2A2E"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="bottom|left"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="TextView"
    />

<!-- 
<View android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"/>
 -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="editusername" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please check it, should i post the java code too. Thanx in advance....

Comment: instead of setting imagebutton background use src property and play with android:scaleType property

Comment: Thanx i got mi answer.....